# Database Supported Haskell on MS Windows

Tags: haskell

I have this error on windows while installing [Pathfinder](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Pathfinder), which is among DSH dependencies. Is it possible to install [DSH](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/DSH) on Windows system?

> D:\Devs>cabal install pathfinder Resolving dependencies... [1 of 1]
>   Compiling Main             (
>   C:\DOCUME~1\kdv\LOCALS~1\Temp\Pathfinder-0
>   .5.103528\Pathfinder-0.5.10\Setup.hs,
>   C:\DOCUME~1\kdv\LOCALS~1\Temp\Pathfinder-0
>   .5.103528\Pathfinder-0.5.10\dist\setup\Main.o ) Linking
>   C:\DOCUME~1\kdv\LOCALS~1\Temp\Pathfinder-0.5.103528\Pathfinder-0.5.10\di
>   st\setup\setup.exe ... setup.exe: The program sh is required but it
>   could not be found. cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
>   Pathfinder-0.5.10 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
>   ExitFailure 1

Answer (score 1):

You can try to compile it using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html) or [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS). You need at least the following command-line tools in your `%PATH%`:

- `sh`
- `rm`
- `cp`
- `tar`
- `pwd`
- `make`
- `ar`
- `ld`

These tools are necessary because the library uses an internal C library, which in turn uses `autotools` and associated `configure` and `Makefile`s, which are interpreted by `sh` and `make` respectively. If you install MSYS or Cygwin, you will have the necessary UNIX-like environment to be able to compile it.

You can of course also just install the library in a Linux environment; you'll have a much easier time because you won't have to potentially deal with MinGW version incompatibilities etc. In your position, I would at least consider installing a virtual machine running some form of Linux distribution and just do all of my development there - that's what I do on my main Windows machine. When you are ready for deployment, it is much easier to cross-compile Windows Haskell programs on Linux than actually compiling on Windows directly because you don't have to deal with version conflicts, and you also have the option to produce a Linux binary for Linux servers (which are what most RDBMS tend to run on, anyways).

Comment: Go with MinGW - MSYS. No-one uses Cygwin to compile bindings, so while Cygwin's suitability might have improved recently using it would take you into uncharted territories...

Comment: I may have missed something, I didn't think it were possible as of yet to cross compile at all.  Though I believe there may be support for that in 7.6.2? If that is the case and you aren't using 7.6.2 could you please share?